# Currently having problems with my routes in my application

Tags: reactjs, react-router

I have the version "react-router-dom": "^5.0.1",and my app is not loading as I saw in a tutorial.

I have tried changing my code because the guy was using an older version.

```
import React from 'react';
import './App.css';
import { BrowserRouter, Route, Switch } from 'react-router-dom'
import about from './components/about';
import work from './components/workSection';
import contact from './components/contact';
import main from './components/main';


function App() {
  return (

    <BrowserRouter>
    <Switch>
    <Route path="/" exact component={main}>
    <Route path={"about"} component={about}/>
    <Route path={"workSection"} component={work}/>
    <Route path={"contact"} component={contact}/>
    </Route>
    </Switch>
    </BrowserRouter>

  );
}

export default App;
```

Whenever I run my application it should open my Main page

Comment: What is the error or issue?

Answer (score 1):

Your value for `path` has to start with `/`. Also, I don't believe you can wrap children `<Route>` inside a parent `<Route>`. You can try this solution:

```
function App() {
  return (
    <BrowserRouter>
      <Switch>
        <Route path="/about" component={about} />
        <Route path="/workSection" component={work} />
        <Route path="/contact" component={contact} />
        <Route path="/" exact component={main} />
      </Switch>
    </BrowserRouter>

  );
}
```

Comment: thank you, for some reason the tutorial I was watching it worked perfectly.

Answer (score 1):

**In `react-router-v4` you don't nest `<Routes />`.**

You should add each route separately. Also each route path should start with `/`.

```
<Switch>
    <Route path="/" exact component={main} />
    <Route path="/about" component={about}/>
    <Route path="/workSection" component={work}/>
    <Route path="/contact" component={contact}/>
</Switch>
```

**Note:** You must use `PascalCase` component names.

Answer (score 0):

Here is the working example https://codesandbox.io/s/eloquent-wildflower-50c6b?fontsize=14

You should start the path with **/** in order to load the routes.

In the above-mentioned example, it will load the `Main` route by default and when you change the URL to `/about` it will load the `about` route